# Unable to pass parameter to controller from view

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

what I am trying to achieve is, when I select a person from dropdown, his phone number should appear on an adjacent textbox on the on change function of the dropdown.
I have been able to get person's name from database in the dropdown.

here's the Model code :

```
 public function get_phone_id($id)
{
    $this->db->select('dealerphone');
    $this->db->where('dealerid',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get('Dealer');
$result=$query->result_array();
    return $result;


}
```

Controller Code:

```
 public function dealer_phone($id)
{

$list = $this->person->get_phone_id($id);
  //  print_r($list);
    echo json_encode($list);


}
```

View Code:

```
  <script>


                    $("#select").change(function () {
                        var getValue = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('id');
                        get_phone(getValue);
                        });




                    function get_phone(id) {
                        alert(id);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo site_url('dealer_controller/dealer_phone')?>/" + id
                            , type: "POST"
                            , dataType: "JSON"
                            , async:false
                            , success: function () {
                                //if success reload ajax table
                              console.log();
                            }
                            , error: function (xhr,status) {
                                console.log(status);
                            }
                        });


                    }




                </script>
```

The only problem I am facing is that I am unable to pass 'getValue' to controller function.

Comment: Can you check in browser console what are request and response values?

Comment: please add your html

Answer (score 0):

Hello you pass data in get method and declare ajax post method so you change data type or passing data

```
function get_phone(id) {
                        alert(id);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo site_url('dealer_controller/dealer_phone')?>"
                            ,data :{id:your variable (id)}
                            , type: "POST"
                            , dataType: "JSON"
                            , async:false
                            , success: function () {
                                //if success reload ajax table
                              console.log();
                            }
                            , error: function (xhr,status) {
                                console.log(status);
                            }
                        });
                        }
```

And you can get this data in controller side this way

```
public function dealer_phone()
{
$list = $this->input->post('id');
  //  print_r($list);
    echo json_encode($list);
}
```